# Menu from the bottom

Tags: android, menu

I want when I click on the menu button a menu appears from the bottom of the screen.

[image: one]

Any suggestions?

Comment: create custom-view and animate it

Answer (score 0):

Create custom view

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/custom_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="64dp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:clickable="true">

    <!-- Anything you need -->

</RelativeLayout>
```

In *onCreate* method initialize view like

```
mCustomView = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.custom_view);
```

In *onOptionsItemSelected* method do next:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.some_menu) {
            mCustomView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            // do some animation there
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```